# Where do I find old Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I need to retrieve old messages I sent to a friend on Facebook from 3 years ago that I didn't delete.

Can I find them and where?

Answer (score 1):

To view your older messages *(messenger chat history)* please follow these 2 simple steps:

**1. Go to `Messages`**
.

[image: face-01]

**2. Choose the thread of the friend you want to search. Scroll all the way till you find the message you want.

*(Optional) If by scrolling you can not find the message, click on `Options` (the little cog) and then on `Open in Messenger` to see all of the messages in a full page.***
.

[image: face-02]

.